# Xamarin Android - Bind Image to GridView using ImageAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to bind Image in GridView which is in Fragment. The fragment is loading but it is blank. I put breakpoint on GetView method of ImageAdapeter but it is not hitting breakpoint. Is it the reason Fragment is blank?

Here is my Code

Fragment code:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.profilefragmentlayout, null);

        var PhotoGridView = root.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.PhotoGridView);

        PhotoGridView.Adapter = new ImageAdapter(root.Context);

        return root;
    }
```

ImageAdapter code

```
    public class ImageAdapter: BaseAdapter
{
    Context contextcreate; 
    public ImageAdapter(Context a)
    {
        contextcreate = a;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return imageIds.Length; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            imageView = new ImageView(contextcreate);
            imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(50, 50);
            imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
            imageView.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        } 
        imageView.SetImageResource(imageIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    } 
    int[] imageIds = { 
        Resource.Drawable.WP1, Resource.Drawable.WP2, 
        Resource.Drawable.WP3, Resource.Drawable.WP4, 
        Resource.Drawable.WP5, Resource.Drawable.WP6, 
        Resource.Drawable.WP7, Resource.Drawable.WP8, 
        Resource.Drawable.WP9, Resource.Drawable.WP10,  
        Resource.Drawable.WP11, Resource.Drawable.WP12,  
    };
}
```

}

Please let me what I am missing which is stopping to bind image in gridview in fragment.

Comment: Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your fragment class

```
 public class OneFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.One, null);
            var gridview = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);
            gridview.Adapter = new ImageAdapter(Activity);

            gridview.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, args.Position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Add ImageAdapter class and add this code in ImageAdapter class

```
 public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return thumbIds.Length; }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null)
            {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
                imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            else
            {
                imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }

            imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        int[] thumbIds = {
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
        Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.Icon,
    };
    }
```

It's work for me